# Xamarin crash on iOS 10 swipe on Listview multiple times

Tags: c#, ios, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Xamarin forms. Version 2.0. I created a listView swipe by add menuItem to ContextActions, showing delete when you swipe left on a cell.
All works fine but if I swipe on a cell to show the delete context, and I swipe on another cell. App crashes. Has anyone come across this issue.

This looks like a Xamarin forms bug.

Comment: My app does not crash when doing the same thing on an iPhone 6 running the latest version of iOS. Perhaps you could include your code to help find the problem.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. This issue is a bug in Xamarin forms 2.0.0. It is fixed in 2.3. Unfortunately we cannot upgrade now as there are too many people using this app in production. Thanks your help.

Comment: You could use Apples Phase Release which goes from 1%, to 2%, 5%, etc. for 7 days, which allows you to stop the release if that 1 or 2%'s phone gets bricked.

Comment: That will not be allowed in an enterprise. This is an enterprise app used by over 4000 staff.